# Css Works fine in browser but not in Android Webview

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I tried to a build a basic template following this [tutorial](http://goratchet.com/getting-started/) using ratchet.I am loading the basic template via android webview.Interestingly the webview only renders a blank page while the browser(chrome) does renders the desired template properly.I did try to debug the web view from chrome(Inspect device) and interestingly when i remove the css property **"position:fixed/absolute"** the web view renders the template properly. [image]
This prevents me from using ratchet,since i cannot inspect and customize each elements.Are there are any other such frameworks that helps to build mobile apps(js+css) that would possibly work with android webview.

Comment: Try embeding Crosswalk which is a chromium brower that replaces webview. Its easy to do -- One problem thought crosswalk is about 22megs so that will be added on to your app -- ive seen a mini version somewere on git hub that doesnt include webgl and all that other excess stuff bulilt in, but one you use crosswalk you never look back cause its fast and it has all chrome browser goodies -- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html

Comment: Can you remove the `ratchet` tag on this question, it is incorrect